# C# TCPClient stream problems

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

I have a client and server, both with methods for receiving and sending, and both are using the same class for packets, packet's header size and deserialization etc.

Everything works if I send smaller packages of just text messages, but when I try to send an image, the buffer overflows and I get an out of memory exception.
The strange part is that it actually finds the correct packetsize from the packet's header, but when it then proceeds to reed the packetsize has changed into odd numbers. 
The image is in form of a byte array inside the packet class.

In the part where it is about to read the actual packet, PacketLength has changed, to either very large numbers or a negative value even.
I am trying to understand why it keeps changing despite not looking for the header size anymore..

I am making sure that the server sends just 1 package, and I am also printing the package size before sending, then checking if the client is receiving said packet.
The client keeps receiving more than it should.

Please help me out :)

**What the server prints out during sending:**

- Headersize: 4
- Packetsize: 123
- Sent 1/1 packets (127 bytes)

**What the client prints out during receiving:**

- Received packet, found size from header: 123
- Start reading packet

(then once the whole packet is read it is added to a list and forwarded to other internal methods to handle the packet based on its type (image, text, etc)

Example with image embedded into the packet:

- Server says: packetsize is 300504 + 4 byte header
- server sent: 1/1 packets (300508bytes)
- client says: received packet with size 300504
- then immediately after it says:
- received too big packet with size 966440806
- (out of memory exeption)

**Server code:**

```
    // This is a threaded TCPclient handler on the server.
    private void _TCP_ManageClient(object clientObj)
    {
        uint clientID = _ClientConnected();
        var client = (TcpClient) clientObj;
        bool connected = true;

        _AddClientFromList(ref client, clientID);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        AddPacketToSend(_Packet_Welcome(clientID)); // Welcome, client #X. message is sent out.

        while (connected) 
        {
            // S E N D     P A C K E T
            SendPacketsInQueue(stream);

            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                // R E C E I V E     P A C K E T
                ReceivePacketsFromStream(stream);

                // R E A D      P A C K E T
                ReadPacketsInQueue(ref connected);
            }
        }
        if (!connected) { Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Client[" + clientID + "] dropped"); }
    }

    // Send packets which are in the format of 'RemuseNetPacket' class.
    public void SendPacketsInQueue(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        if (m_SendMessageList.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] packetBytes;
            byte[] readyData;
            int byteCount = 0;
            int sentPackets = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m_SendMessageList.Count; i++)
            {
                packetBytes = m_SendMessageList[i].Serialize();
                Int32 headersize = packetBytes.Length;
                byte[] packetLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(headersize);
                Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Header size: " + headersize);
                Con.Add(m_Logtag, "PacketLength: " + packetLength.Length);
                readyData = Extensions.Concatenate(packetLength, packetBytes);
                stream.Write(readyData, 0, readyData.Length);
                byteCount += readyData.Length;
                sentPackets++;
            }
            Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Sent " + sentPackets + "/" + m_SendMessageList.Count + " packets (" + byteCount + " bytes)");
            int r = m_SendMessageList.Count;
            m_SendMessageList.Clear();
            Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Removed " + r + " sent packages from list");
        }
    }
```

**Client code:**

```
// This is the client's TCP loop.
        private void _TCPClientStart()
        {
            try
            {
                TCPClient = new TcpClient();
                TCPClient.Connect(m_HostIP, m_Port);
                Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Connected to " + m_HostIP + ":" + m_Port);
                m_IsRunning = true;
                m_Connected = true;
                NetworkStream stream = TCPClient.GetStream();

                AddPacketToSend(_Packet_Hello()); // Hello, I am [computer name]. message is sent out.

                while (m_Connected)
                {
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        // R E C E I V E     P A C K E T
                        ReceivePacketsFromStream(stream);

                        // R E A D      P A C K E T
                        ReadPacketsInQueue();
                    }
                    // S E N D      P A C K E T
                    SendPacketsInQueue(stream);
                }
                Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Con.Add(m_Logtag, "TCPclient Exception: " + e.ToString());
                Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Stacktrace: " + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        // Client receives a packet.
        private void ReceivePacketsFromStream(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            int PacketLength = -1;
            int BytesRead = 0;
            byte[] ReceivedBytes = new byte[0];

            while (stream != null && stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                // Read packet's header (first 4 bytes)
                if (PacketLength < 0)
                {
                    if (BytesRead == 0) { ReceivedBytes = new byte[m_HeaderLength]; }

                    BytesRead += stream.Read(ReceivedBytes, BytesRead, (ReceivedBytes.Length - BytesRead));

                    if (BytesRead == m_HeaderLength)
                    {
                        PacketLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(ReceivedBytes, 0);

                        // Obtained information about the packet's size.
                        if (PacketLength < m_MaxPacketSize)
                        {
                            Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Received packet header, packet size: " + PacketLength);
                            BytesRead = 0;
                            Array.Clear(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Received too big packet: " + PacketLength);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Start reading packet content.
                else
                {
                    Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Start reading packet");

                    if (BytesRead == 0) { ReceivedBytes = new byte[PacketLength]; }
                    BytesRead += stream.Read(ReceivedBytes, BytesRead, (ReceivedBytes.Length - BytesRead));

                    // Whole packet obtained.
                    if (BytesRead >= PacketLength)
                    {
                        RemuseNetPacket packet = new RemuseNetPacket();
                        packet = packet.Desserialize(ReceivedBytes);
                        Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Received packet #" + packet.ID);

                        // Add packet to list for reading.
                        if (packet != null) { AddPacketToRead(packet); }
                        BytesRead = 0;
                        PacketLength = -1;
                        Array.Clear(ReceivedBytes, 0, ReceivedBytes.Length);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

**edit: adding image packet type code**

```
    private RemuseNetPacket _Packet_Screen()
    {
        Con.Add(m_Logtag, "Send Image packet");
        RemuseNetPacket p = new RemuseNetPacket();
        p.Type = RemusePacketType.Image;

// captures the screen with the mouse (true) using format jpeg.
        p.Data = ScreenCapture.CaptureToBytes(true, m_ImageFormat);
        Con.Add(m_Logtag, "package img size: " + p.Data.Length);
        p.SenderName = m_Name;
        p.Timestamp = _GetCurrentTimestamp();
        return p;
    }
```

This is what the log says about the weird packet size:

```
[Active] Host:  Send Image packet (this is where i sent 1 image packet)
[Active] Host:  removed 1 sent packages from list
[Active] Client:  Start reading packet
[Active] Client:  Received data: 74456 / 327332 (this is the actual packet size)
[Active] Client:  Received packet header, packet size: -251848753 (suddenly it becomes this..)
[Active] Client:  Start reading packet
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
[Active] Client:  Received data: 4 / 1251185707
```

Comment: you should not use `stream.DataAvailable` to indicate an end condition; that *isn't what it means*; that just tells you whether *right now* there is data in the local buffers; it doesn't indicate any kind of end condition

Comment: You seem to indicate that the packet size (`PacketLength`?) is giving unexpected values; can you indicate what you expected vs what you received? also: can you show the *write* code?

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi Marc, I've updated the thread with some more code for you, please have a look.

Comment: Is the problem that it never finishes reading the packet? if so: do you have nagle enabled on the socket? it is enabled by default; try setting `NoDelay=true` on the socket

Comment: Additionally: have you checked the length of the array coming back from `Extensions.Concatenate` (i.e. `readyData`) ? is it *actually* 127 bytes?

Comment: @MarcGravell What the server sends is correct, and other packets are received just fine such as chat messages, they are received just once. It's only the larger one with image that causes it to behave strangely.

Comment: "What the server sends is correct" - have you **checked** that? or do you just *believe* that? I do a **lot** of socket work (no, really; a lot), and I never trust **anything** is right until I've actually manually inspected the bytes (and the lengths)

Comment: @MarcGravell I _believe_ it is true. I print out the various information about packet size, length, headers in every part of creating the packet until it has been sent. Then I also print out the received data and its sizes on the client.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've updated the thread a little bit with example for sending an image

Comment: Instead of adding dribs and drabs of more information, could you try to create a [mcve] please? I.e. you tell us what the code is "printing out" but we don't know where that's happening because the code you're showing us doesn't contain *any* output code. A *complete* example that we can compile and run on our own machines would help a *lot* here. (But also, minimal would also help - don't show us lots of code that isn't relevant to the problem)

Comment: The extra logging info is great, but I can't see where it logs those; I would need to be able to see what lines print "received packet with size 300504", "received too big packet with size 966440806", and what happens in between - because it sounds like the problem is *between those two things*

Comment: Frankly, your overly complicated read loop also makes it hard to debug; I **strongly suggest** you simplify to something more like my answer, and see if that just makes everything better

Comment: @MarcGravell My loop is something I got from asking here earlier. Regarding the logging, I had taken that out of the pasted code here in order to make it more compact. This site's text formatting is a pain once you have a lot of text to paste .. Give me some moments and I will paste it all

Comment: k; now we're getting somewhere; does it do this on the **very first** packet? or after a few? If it happens from the start, then I'm suspicious of the contents of the length-prefix data, which again makes me suspicious of `Extensions.Concatenate`. Otherwise, it is most likely screwing up the lengths in that horrible loop, and again I'd advise something much simpler. Whoever wrote that loop for you (here on stackoverflow): didn't do you any favors

Comment: The only *logical* way to receive a message `received packet with size ...` immediately followed by `received too big packet with size ...` is if the `while` loop inside `ReceivePacketsFromStream` is exiting and then we're going around in another loop inside `_TCPClientStart` and reentering `ReceivePacketsFromStream`. So, as Marc pointed out in the *very first* comment - you're while loop's exit condition is suspect.

Comment: @MarcGravell I can send any other type of packet, such as chat messages just fine, as many as a I want, and they are received one by one and read properly. It only happens when I embed an image into the packet. It will read its size properly once, then it goes crazy and keeps on reading and reading until memory runs out. Despite that it was sent just once

Comment: @MadsM great; so you have a repro scenario; now you just need need to step through that scenario with breakpoints to figure out what edge condition causes that to happen; it'll be something to do with tracking the various numbers over the loop. Or, and I realize I'm sounding a bit repetitive here, save yourself all that pain and just use a simpler loop :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm new to network programming, so it is very rudamentary now, but I'd like to make it more efficient for the long run eventually. I've updated the thread with some log records

Comment: Again. Look at the outputs. The only way they make sense is if the entire `ReceivePacketsFromStream` method is exiting *before it's read an entire packet*. And then, when it's re-entered, all the variables are reset and it's *expecting* to read a header, when in fact it's reading 4 random bytes from the middle of the previous packet and interpreting *that* as the data size.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the `Extensions.Concatenate()` method from my classes? (I provided you with an answer a while back that linked to another answer with a set of TCP handling classes). If the method is from them, I just wanted to say that there's an easier way of using it. As it is an extension it can be called on the byte array immediately, like so: `readyData = packetLength.Concatenate(packetBytes);`

Comment: Actually, the entire read method seems to be from those... Did you change anything in them, or did I do a mistake? I have not had such problems so far (though I only use the VB.NET version, which have proven to work completely). Guess I'll have to go examine that code again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to diagnose specifically, but here's a more typical read loop for this scenario; a lot simpler and probably easier to debug:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
while(true) {
    if(!Fill(stream, buffer, 4)) break;
    int len = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    if(buffer.Length < len) buffer = new byte[len]; // need moar!
    if(!Fill(stream, buffer, len)) throw new EndOfStreamException();
    ProcessData(buffer, len); // note: only look at the first "len" bytes
}

static bool Fill(Stream source, byte[] destination, int count) {
    int bytesRead, offset = 0;
    while(count > 0 &&
        (bytesRead = source.Read(destination, offset, count)) > 0)
    {
        offset += bytesRead;
        count -= bytesRead;
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```